# How can I improve this glm and do I need to dummy code?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, residuals, beta-distribution

I have percentage disease data taken from leaves of wheat in a disease trial which were artificially inoculated with isolates of disease from different source plants.

The basic question is, are disease isolates sourced from the same cultivar better at infecting those cultivars? We are looking for an interaction. 
I am trying to conduct a logit linked beta glm to determine if there is an interaction between the source cultivar variable and the inoculated host cultivar variable.

My model looks something like this:

```
beta_model=betareg(mean.proportion.disease ~ Source.CV + inoculant.Host +
                 Source.CV*Inoculant.Host, data = study, link =c('logit'))
```

I have also tried a binomial glm:

```
binom_model = glm(mean.proportion.disease ~ Source.CV + inoculant.Host + 
                 Source.CV*Inoculant.Host,
               data = study, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
```

Both models give me residuals that look like this:

[image: residuals of betareg model]

Is there any way I can improve on this and get normal residuals?
I might also be worth noting that there are a few zeros in my data so proportions are transformed according to:  $(y*(n-1)+0.5)/n)$.

Lastly, you've probably already guessed I am a beginner in this realm of statistics, and as such I'm thinking about glm's in the context of simple linear regression. So I can't really understand what the intercept in glm output is telling me, if anyone can help me with this I'd very grateful.

Any comments appreciated.

Comment: Given the name of you outcome variable, `mean.proportion.disease`, and the beta-distribution tag, I assume that this variable is measured on a 0-1 scale. So may I ask why you are using logit here?

Comment: To me it looks like there are naturally occurring groupings in the data that need to be accounted for by your model. Can you relate these residuals back to their source?

Comment: thank you for your comments. the groupings probably relate to the three inoculant host plants used in the trial. there were three, one very susceptible to the disease, one moderately resistant, and one very resistant. this would result in proportions that could be grouped as high, medium, and low. variance about these proportions probably reflect this. in answer to why i used logit i'm afraid i must plead ignorance, this model has been succesfully constructed in sas by our resident statistician, and i am now trying to implement it in r as i know nothing about sas. in his sas he used logit.

Comment: A logit link is perfectly acceptable for modelling a percent or proportion, even one that is continuous. If some previous comments are implying that you must have 0, 1 data, that is not the case.

Comment: It looks as if you are already averaging somehow, because your response is `mean.proportion.disease`. Is that so? Otherwise put, what is a data point, or a raw observation? Is it a leaf, diseased or not?

Comment: the disease proportions used in the data set are average percentage disease of six leaves taken from the same plant treatment. with respect to the experimental design each mean is an individual combination of isolate source and inoculant host.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, "typical" regression methods aren't appropriate since your dependent variable is bounded below at 0 and above at 1. You probably want to consider some type of truncated regression appropriate for limited dependent variables such as this. Here's a Wiki reference that has some use in explaining the motivations for using these functional forms:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_regression_model

Broadly speaking, truncated regression is a subset of generalized linear modeling whose development spans separate disciplines such as biology, economics and statistics. Maddala's more than 30 year old book *Limited-Dependent and Qualitative Variables in Econometrics* is the canonical source for a discussion of these topics:

[http://www.amazon.com/Limited-Dependent-Qualitative-Econometrics-Econometric-Monographs-ebook/dp/B00IE6MRUI/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1446038429&sr=1-1&keywords=qualitative+and+limited+dependent+variables](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IE6MRUI)

However, it's a field that has exploded since his book was written and I would be hard-pressed to give you a single reference that summarizes all of the issues, particularly from a bio-statistics POV.

One tip would be to look into beta-binomial models which are a form of probabilistic (i.e., bounded or truncated) modeling that may be appropriate for your percentages. This could leverage an R module designed to integrate the compound function, as opposed to two separate modules as developed here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bbmle/vignettes/mle2.pdf

Comment: But the OP is not using typical regression methods at all. The logit link is tailor-made for the bounds of [0, 1] or [0, 100%]. I think you need a really strong case that truncated regression is even competitive with that kind of approach, let alone superior. The answer doesn't really address this comparison. Moreover, truncated regression can, I suggest, only with extreme difficulty be shoe-horned into the generalized linear model framework: what link function would you say it was using?

Comment: (Naturally other links such as probit, loglog, cloglog could also make sense for bounded proportions.)

Comment: @NickCox Evidently I misread his comments. I thought he was using a functional form which presumed a 0,1 target variable and my response is couched with that assumption

Comment: Percentage disease and logit link GLMs are clearly explained in the post.

Comment: @NickCox  Not everyone is as lucid a reader of the same information, which a more careful parsing on my part would have uncovered. By way of a mea culpa, it looked to me as though the OP was executing separate models for each step of a compound process. Hence, the reference to the complete beta-binomial R module at the end.

Comment: Quite so. But I suggest that some editing of your answer would bring it closer to the question.

Comment: @NickCox  That's a reasonable suggestion, I'm sure, if one agrees with you that truncated models are inferior or less than competitive. The OPs challenges do not lend themselves to cookbook recipes where the answers can be looked up in the back of a text. In addition, I'm sure you'll agree that your opinions in this regard is one among many and that proponents of the methodology might take issue. In my view, my response is valid and suggestive of possible approaches to try, one's that you don't agree with. That being said, are you suggesting that I edit out the word "typical?" I can do that

Comment: In short, no. You have already sprinkled many of your answers and comments on CV with candid criticisms of various kinds and given that you reasonably ask me to clarify, then I will do the same here. My own opinion is that only the beta-binomial suggestion in your answer looks at all related to the question. The other comments on truncated regression are, it seems,  based on misreading the question or to me not yet shown to be related to the question. Any function for a response that doesn't change behaviour as it approaches result 0 or result 1 is utterly unbiological (in this case).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30824/discussion-between-djohnson-and-nick-cox).

Comment: Thanks; I would rather that the discussion remain for others to judge and comment if and as they see fit.

Comment: Fair enough! And it's true about my "candid" comments. "Criticisms" is a somewhat more loaded, adjudicating choice of words reflecting of a bias or disapproval on your part. As far as I'm concerned, I'm not wedded to any method one way or the other. It was merely a thought and a suggestion, again, one that you don't agree with based on your, evidently, superior knowledge of the methodologies. For my part, I'm interested in understanding more about your objections to it from an applied POV with an emphasis on the practicality of the approaches.

Comment: The criticisms referred to were yours, e.g. a comment on "siloed experts of each discipline", where I happen to agree strongly, although the style is not quite mine. No matter; in this case, the absence of a dataset inhibits play and experimentation, but my experience is that the functional form is usually more important than which distribution family one posits. The point about link functions adjusting to the boundaries is not mine but standard across biostatistics, for example.

Comment: Cool. You have a lot of knowledge to share and I welcome the opportunity to absorb that sort of thing. Actually, this is the single biggest reason why I, personally, have chosen to participate on CV -- to learn and to share. So, thank you for that. I'm relieved to note that you didn't think my suggestion was "wrong," merely that it was...sub-optimal?

Comment: The "candid" comment where I really pushed the line was probably the one about "naive" questions wrt factor analysis...I held my breath on that one.

Comment: I think it would be difficult to make a case that a truncated regression model is appropriate for such data, but maybe I have overlooked some nuance. Is there any truncation mechanism at work here?  Or are you proposing this model not because it is suggested by the circumstances, but simply because maybe it would work? In either case, it would seem important to provide some elaboration.  (cc @NickCox)

Comment: Ah! "Truncation mechanisms" That focuses the discussion on the real merits of the suggestion. No, there doesn't seem to be a truncation mechanism at work here, merely that the data is bounded at 0 and 1. Thanks.